# singleton class in objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, design-patterns

I want to have one object that is initialized in the delegate and I want to be able to use this object anywhere across view controllers (doesn't depend on what view I am currently at). I am guessing the solution to this would be to have a singleton class, so far I have the following:

```
@interface LocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    NSDate *enter;
    NSDate *exit;
    CLLocationManager * manager;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * enter;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * exit;

- (BOOL)registerRegionWithLatitude:(double)latitude andLongitude:(double)longitude;
+ (LocationManager *)instance;

@end


#import "LocationManager.h"

@implementation LocationManager
@synthesize enter;
@synthesize exit;

#pragma mark - CLLocationManager delegate
static LocationManager *gInstance = NULL;


+ (LocationManager *)instance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (gInstance == NULL)
            gInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return(gInstance);
}

@end
```

Is this correct? So all I need to do to access this is just to call instance? Inside LocationManager I also want to have only one CLLocationManager, called manager.. however, where do I initialize it so I only have one? Can I do the following? Most other singleton examples doesn't have any variables in the class, so that's where I got confused

```
+ (LocationManager *)sharedLocationManager
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (lm == NULL){
            lm = [[self alloc] init];
            lm.manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            lm.manager.delegate = lm;
        }
    }
    return(lm);
}
```

Comment: Googling "objective-c singleton" reveals many thousands of hits.

Comment: I would name it `sharedLocationManager` instead of `instance`. Apple name them this way (except for `NSNull` and `NSUserDefaults`, but these are special).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically -- yes.
Just a couple of small things:
`static LocationManager *gInstance = NULL;`
instead of `NULL`, you should use `nil`, it's a convention in Objective-C.

You should also overwrite `alloc`, `new`, `copyWithZone:`, and `mutableCopyWithZone:`. From Buck/Yacktman: "Cocoa Design Patterns", p. 153:

```
+ (id)hiddenAlloc  
{
  return [super alloc];
}

+ (id)new
{
  return [self alloc];
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
  return [[self sharedInstance] retain];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
  [self retain];
  return self;
}

- (id)mutableCopyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
  return [self copyWithZone:zone];
}
```

This way, your singleton object cannot be copied. You need to call `hiddenAlloc` from your `instance` method (by the way, the method to access a Singleton object is often called `sharedInstance` in Objective-C).

Comment: how about that CLLocationManager?

Comment: couple things: since `alloc` simply calls `allocWithZone:`, you don't need to override them both.  `allocWithZone:` should simply return the singleton instance (retained of course) so that if you try to alloc/init a new instance, you just get the singleton back.

Comment: the one thing I am confused is with having one instance of CLLocationManager as well in this singleton class..

Answer (score 0):

For other singleton styles with their pros and cons, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like).

Personally, I prefer this style (copied from one of the answers on that link):

```
static MySingleton *sharedSingleton;

+ (void)initialize
{
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if(!initialized)
    {
        initialized = YES;
        sharedSingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    }
}
```

Comment: The only downside with your answer is, this will not be exactly "lazy loading". Since even if a class method for MySingleton is called, the sharedInstance object will be created immediately.

Comment: Whether or not it is a "downside" depends on your needs. At least for the original question "lazy loading" was not stated as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there's a tried-and-true method to create singletons already. Download the [SynthesizeSingleton.h](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/SynthesizeSingleton.h.zip) file (from a [Cocoa with Love article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html)). It contains a massive amount of pre-processor code which will generate any singleton for you. Hit the article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since the factory method "instance" is a class-level method, the @synchronized block should be
@synchronized([LocationManager class]) {
//}

Comment: `self` in a class method refers to the class, so that the original code works as intended, at least in this regard.

Comment: There's already a singleton class in your code, AppDelegate class.
You should ideally avoid creating a singleton, unless very explicitly required.
Probably, in your case the location manager code may be simply set in AppDelegat, and the coordinates made as property in AppDelegate class.