# Call function in a different view

Tags: iphone, xcode, function, view

Need help for that.

I have a tabbar with 2 views, A and B (tableviews).

In view B viewDidLoad i call `[self start];` which is a `NSMutableURLRequest`.

```
   -(void)start
    {
    NSMutableURLRequest  * //my code here....


NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%d", [myArray count]];

[(UIViewController*)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem].badgeValue =temp;

    }
```

I need to call this function `-(void)start` from my view A to have a badgeValue in my viewController objectAtIndex:1;

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can use Singleton pattern, take a look at this post [singleton class in objective-C][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438629/singleton-class-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I understand you you need a reference to your view B to call the start method...

In view A:

```
UITableView* b = a;
[b start];
```

Or do I not understand your question?

Comment: i try this but it dont work: myViewB *B = [[myViewB alloc]init];
        [B start];

Answer (score 0):

What i understand that you want to access a value from an array at index row 1. View A should have that value.

So what i recommend is create a class function for view B. Assign the value to the instance of the class function. Now declare a instance of View B in View and call that function.

Hope it helps.